# Can't start MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have just installed MongoDB following this tutorial: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

After installing MongoDB, I store it at the following location: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard`.

After starting the command prompt as an administrator I do the following:

```
mkdir c:\data\db
mkdir c:\data\log

echo logpath=c:\data\log\mongod.log> "C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\mongod.cfg"
echo dbpath=c:\data\db>> "C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\mongod.cfg"

sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB 2.6 Standard" start= "auto"
```

After that, when I want to start the actual service I type: `net start MongoDB`.

But nothing happens. The feedback I get is that the "*service doesn't respond to the control function*" (It is directly translated from Swedish).

What can I do to start my MongoDB?

Comment: Take a look inside the log files - perhaps there will be more info on errors there.

Comment: My c:\data\log is empty. Is that wrong?

Comment: Can you include the contents of "C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\mongod.cfg"; there may be invalid options. It also looks like you have extra escaping on your `sc.exe` commandline. There are instructions on how to [manually create a Windows service for MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#manually-create-windows-service) in the documentation, but if you installed MongoDB 2.6.2 or newer using the MSI installer a service definition should already have been created for you.

Answer (score 0):

In bin, paste this in notepad 'mongod --dbpath C:\MongoDB\data' and save it as windows batch file and start this batch file. later in cmd, type mongo and press enter. I hope it will start

Comment: Does it matter what I will call the file? Should I call it mongo?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
Move Mongo from Progam Files (for easiest handly) and rename, for instance *D:mongodb, c|d:* wherever you want

Into *d.\mongodb* create folder data (to store ddbb)
Into *d:\mongo\bin* create *mongodb.config* and add this line:

```
dbpath=d:\mongodb\data
```

With this config you indicate mongo where's tha path to storage

Next open two prompts: The one for start mongo shell:

```
cd mongodb/bin && mongod.exe
```

With this window you can see which version is using

within second prompt window, to start client:

```
cd mongodb/bin && mongo.exe
```

There you can work to create your new database instructions